# Generating many random variables from few string variables

Tags: r

I would like to generate 100 random variables of letters from these four letters (A,C,T,G), how do i go about this

Comment: See `?sample`. for example `sample(c(1, 3, 5), 10, replace=TRUE)` You may also be interested in `replicate`.

Answer (score 1):

How about function sample

```
sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 100, replace = T)
```

Comment: Thats correct, i am trying to come up with a dataframe of this variable and other 100 random variables, to have 2 columns, its bringing me levels